# using php to send AT commands to a mobile phone over bluetooth

Tags: php, sms, bluetooth, serial-port, at-command

I'm using windows 7 and connected my phone using bluetooth. This connection uses a virtual COM port for communication, which I've configured to specified baud rate, flow control, word length, etc. before I call my php function

```
function sendmsg($str = 'AT\r\n', $device = 'COM5'){
  $handle = fopen($device, "w+b");
  stream_set_blocking($handle, 0);
  fwrite($handle, $str);
  fclose($handle);
  return true;
}
```

Now the problem is **fopen()** throws me an error saying that it is an invalid argument and it has failed to opened stream and all else fails. But my phone says it is connected to my computer and then flashes an alert that bluetooth connection has failed. When I tried the same configuration parameters over PuTTY I was able to do what I wanted to do.
I've also tried it on C# but that too ended up with the same result **:(**

Comment: Well, what does `$device` contain? Not sure whether this is possible at all in Windows 7, though.

Comment: $device = 'com5' When I execute this it creates a connection and then fails which means there is a possibility. But I'm missing out something :(

Comment: What does `COM5:` instead of `COM5` result in?

Comment: Did you try "COM5:" with double colon?

Comment: tried it and it's the same... also, trying com5 on cmd resulted in the same

Comment: PHP can deal with Unix device names `/dev/ttyS2` well, but DOS/Windows [device specifiers might be inaccessible](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/74496) over the file API. Try expliciting `\DEV\COM5` if you must (not always enabled).

Comment: that article says we cannot name files using the reserved names. anyway, tried what u said and it says 'no such file or directory found'

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/

Comment: this class uses the same technique (look at the send message function) and configuration is explicitly done using exec(mode com) which can also be done in the device manager... thanks for the reply, anyway :)

Comment: At a glance it looks like it's converting `COM5` to `\\.\com5`. Did you try that?

Comment: yeah, i did that with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar but in Python and it worked - Windows Vista talking with a Nokia N70 phone. The phone was paired over bluetooth and the communication it was done using a COM port created along with pairing. It was based on a open source project called [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/)